# Spring, Hibernate, JPA: Lazy loading id's

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently in the process of converting a large project from Grails to Spring: I'm somewhat stuck when attempting to lazy-load objects id's without having to select the entire table.

The way I would like it to work, `/Object/`:

```
Object
    List<child> children
```

to be output like so:

```
{children:[{id:1},{id:2}]}
```

So that from another controller I can then access that inner object if required using regular CRUD methods which I have implemented across all of my controllers. `/child/1`

With the JSON output in mind, I'm having trouble with no Session being available during serialization which is understandable, I've seen methods such as calling `object.child.getId()` in the service layer seems incredibly hacky to me and would also cause the entire object to be Lazily-loaded.

Overall, I'm looking to create a simple Rest Application with easy customization of the json output, something grails did with the JSON Marshalling plugin really quite well: https://grails.org/plugin/marshallers

Edit:
I don't really wish to set eager loading, but Eager loading is a possibility. Is there a way of getting Eager Loading with a max depth?

```
{ 
  children: { //depth 1
              children-children: { //depth 2 (Ignore this) 
              } 
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use (this is basically a wrapper for object.child.getId hack):

```
Hibernate.initialize(object.getChildren());
```

Or create a special query for this (this would be eager loading with max depth of 1):

```
#assuming you use hql, it would look like this
SELECT e FROM Entity e 
    JOIN FETCH e.children...
```

It is possible to do with CriteriaAPI and DetachedCriteria as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchMode.html#SUBSELECT), so that all uninitialized entities are fetched with a single secondary query, upon accessing.

You only need to make sure, the Hibernate Session is still opened when the uninitialized LAZY association gets accessed.